# Apple Script - How to I check if an iCloud Drive file has been updated from another device?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, catalina

Is there a way to check, via applescript, which device has updated a file stored in iCloud Drive? I know that the terminal command `mdls [file path]` lists lots of metadata. Does any of it identify which devices have modified a file?

Comment: Same as with any other file probably: check for timestamp or content changes. Are you asking about the approach as such or about how to code it with AppleScript?

Comment: I'm wondering if somewhere in the file's metadata there is info about which device edited a file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Who knows :-) Might be worth another question though.

Comment: I just changed it @nohillside

Comment: There is quite a lot, including tools and an analysis on how metadata works with iCloud, on this here: https://eclecticlight.co/tag/icloud/

Comment: One can obtain information about the local copy of an iCloud file using AppleScriptObjC [**`NSURL`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc) file resource keys for [_ubiquitous items_](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlisubiquitousitemkey?language=objc), such as the sync status of the file, whether or not the local version is the most recent copy, and the name of the editor that most recently edited the file.  I can't say for certain whether or not device information is available through one of the myriad keys, but it might be.